# Why is this simple CUDA kernel getting a wrong result?

Tags: c++, c, cuda

I am a newbie with CUDA. I'm learning some basic things because I want to use CUDA in other project. I have wrote this code in order to add all the elements from a squared matrix 8x8 which has been filled with 1's so the result must be 64.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

const int SIZE = 64;


__global__ void add_matrix_values(int* matrix, int sum, int c)
{

    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    int j = threadIdx.y + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;

    sum += matrix[i*c+j];

}



int main()
{
    
    int* device_matrix;
    int* host_matrix;
    int c = 8;      //Squared matrix cxc
    int device_c = 8;
    int device_sum =  0;
    int host_sum  = 0;

    //Allocate host memory
    host_matrix = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    //Fill the matrix values with 1's
    for(auto i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        host_matrix[i] = 1;
    
    //Allocate device memory
    cudaMalloc((void**) &device_matrix,sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &device_sum, sizeof(int));
    cudaMalloc((void**) &device_c,sizeof(int));

    //Fill device_matrix with host_matrix values
    cudaMemcpy(&device_matrix,&host_matrix,sizeof(int)*SIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Initialize device_sum with a 0 
    cudaMemcpy(&device_sum,&host_sum,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Initialize device_c with the correct value
    cudaMemcpy(&device_c,&c,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    //4 blocks with 16 threads every single block ¿Is this correct?
    add_matrix_values<<<4,16>>>(device_matrix, device_sum,device_c);

    cudaMemcpy(&host_sum,&device_sum,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    std::cout<<"The value is: "<<host_sum<<std::endl;


    cudaFree(device_matrix);
    free(host_matrix);

    return 0;




}
```

The result must be 64 but I'm getting wrong numbers.

```
 migue@migue  ~/Escritorio  ./program
The value is: 32762
 migue@migue  ~/Escritorio  ./program
The value is: 32608
 migue@migue  ~/Escritorio  ./program
The value is: 32559
```

I dont't know what I'm doing wrong. It could be the gridSize and the blockSize ? or It could be the i and j operation in the cuda Kernel ?

I dont understand very well that terms.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are a number of issues:

- You are creating a 1-D grid (grid configuration, block configuration) so your 2-D indexing in kernel code (i,j, or x,y) doesn't make any sense
- You are passing `sum` by value.  You cannot retrieve a result that way.  Changes in the kernel to `sum` won't be reflected in the calling environment.  This is a C++ concept, not specific to CUDA.  Use a properly allocated pointer instead.
- In a CUDA multithreading environment, you cannot have multiple threads update the same location/value without any control.  CUDA does not sort out that kind of access for you.  You must use a parallel reduction technique, and a simplistic approach here could be to use atomics.  You can find many questions here on the `cuda` tag discussing parallel reductions.
- You're generally confusing pass by value and pass by pointer.  Items passed by value can be ordinary host variables.  You generally don't need a `cudaMalloc` allocation for those.  You also don't use `cudaMalloc` on any kind of variable except a pointer.
- Your use of `cudaMemcpy` is incorrect.  There is no need to take the address of the pointers.

The following code has the above items addressed:

```
$ cat t135.cu
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>

const int SIZE = 64;


__global__ void add_matrix_values(int* matrix, int *sum, int c)
{

    int i = threadIdx.x + blockIdx.x * blockDim.x;
    atomicAdd(sum, matrix[i]);

}



int main()
{

    int* device_matrix;
    int* host_matrix;
    int device_c = 8;
    int *device_sum;
    int host_sum  = 0;

    //Allocate host memory
    host_matrix = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    //Fill the matrix values with 1's
    for(auto i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
        host_matrix[i] = 1;

    //Allocate device memory
    cudaMalloc((void**) &device_matrix,sizeof(int)*SIZE);
    cudaMalloc((void**) &device_sum, sizeof(int));

    //Fill device_matrix with host_matrix values
    cudaMemcpy(device_matrix,host_matrix,sizeof(int)*SIZE,cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    //Initialize device_sum with a 0
    cudaMemcpy(device_sum,&host_sum,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);


    //4 blocks with 16 threads every single block Â¿Is this correct?
    add_matrix_values<<<4,16>>>(device_matrix, device_sum,device_c);

    cudaMemcpy(&host_sum,device_sum,sizeof(int),cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

    std::cout<<"The value is: "<<host_sum<<std::endl;


    cudaFree(device_matrix);
    free(host_matrix);

    return 0;

}
$ nvcc -o t135 t135.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t135
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
The value is: 64
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```